# How do I unlock additional kart parts?

Tags: mario-kart-7

I'm looking to unlock all of the additional kart parts, but I'm not sure how to unlock them. How do I unlock additional parts for my karts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997822-mario-kart-7/cheats):

> You can earn 10 coins per race, 40 per cup.
>   **Unlockable - How to Unlock**
>   Random Part 1 - 50 coins
>   Random Part 2 - 100 coins
>   Random Part 3 - 150 coins
>   Random Part 4 - 200 coins
>   Random Part 5 - 250 coins
>   Random Part 6 - 300 coins
>   Random Part 7 - 400 coins
>   Random Part 8 - 500 coins
>   Random Part 9 - 600 coins
>   Random Part 10 - 700 coins
>   Random Part 11 - 800 coins
>   Random Part 12 - 900 coins
>   Random Part 13 - 1000 coins
>   Random Part 14 - 1200 coins
>   Random Part 15 - 1400 coins
>   Random Part 16 - 1600 coins
>   Random Part 17 - 1800 coins
>   Random Part 18 - 2000 coins
>   Random Part 19 - 2500 coins
>   Random Part 20 - 3000 coins
>   Random Part 21 - 3500 coins
>   Random Part 22 - 4000 coins
>   Random Part 23 - 4500 coins
>   Beast Glider - 5000 coins
>   Gold Glider - Connect with 100 people via StreetPass or collect 10,000 coins
>   Gold Standard (kart body) - Obtain a VR higher than 10,000 points or collect 20,000 coins
>   Golden Steering Wheel - Play 100 recent matches and use the first person gyro controls 80% of the time
>   Golden Wheels - Beat every cup on 50cc, 100cc, 150cc and Mirror Mode and receive a minimum of 1 star ranking for each cup to unlock

Comment: Do they just unlock at the end of a race?

Comment: Also, does this just apply to grand prix races, or do multiplayer races count too?

Comment: @Wipqozn: After you return to a menu screen, it will alert you whether you've unlocked anything new or not. And yes, coins will be recorded even in multiplayer matches.

Comment: It will alert you when something is unlocked, and next time you pick car parts a new option will be waiting to be revealed.

I was wondering if online races work. My friend said no, but I think I unlocked something after playing online. It doesn't always seem to work though. Or maybe it doesn't work as well.

I've also been wondering if you only keep the coins you are holding at race end? I'm assuming yes, so if you get bashed before the finish line and lose half your coins, it sucks.