# How do I know how many coins I've collected?

Tags: mario-kart-7

[Additional Kart parts are unlocked by collecting coins.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43816/how-do-i-unlock-additional-kart-parts) That is all fine and dandy, but how do I know how many coins I've collected across all games? This would make it much easier to know when I've collected all Kart parts, and how far away I am from unlocking an additional part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must go to the Mario Kart Channel and investigate the face of your Mii in the bottom-right corner. There you'll see:

- Your VR
- Your online win/loss record
- **Your coin count**
- Your StreetPass count
- Customization options for StreetPass/SpotPass